# gulp gh-pages not working

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

everything worked fine before but today.. isn't.. not sure why, here is the error:

```
/Users/harpreetsingh/Downloads/folio-cedrik/node_modules/gift/lib/commit.js:145
      ref1 = /^.+? (.*) (\d+) .*$/.exec(line), m = ref1[0], actor = ref1[1], epoch = ref1[2];
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Function.module.exports.Commit.actor (/Users/harpreetsingh/Downloads/folio-cedrik/node_modules/gift/lib/commit.js:145:56)
    at Function.module.exports.Commit.parse_commits (/Users/harpreetsingh/Downloads/folio-cedrik/node_modules/gift/lib/commit.js:111:21)
    at /Users/harpreetsingh/Downloads/folio-cedrik/node_modules/gift/lib/commit.js:71:39
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:189:7)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

How can this be fixed? No idea what this means.

Thank you once again.

Comment: What causes this error to be emitted?

Comment: ref1 is a null object

Comment: Yeah, but that's being thrown by the [`gift` npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gift), which was updated 3 days ago. I smell upstream regression.

Comment: @Harp, post your `package.json` and tell us what you did to provoke this error, please. Do you run a command `gulp gh-pages`? If so, more context would be helpful, because whatever comes after `gulp` is just the name of your gulp task and is not universal, so probably post your `gulpfule.js`, too.

Comment: In my case this problem occurred after having multiple collaborators in the repo

Comment: I don't know exactly how to fix the underlying problem, but I did find that this fork still works: https://github.com/justeat/gulp-gh-pages

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still having this problem who happens to also be using Yarn, I added a field to "resolutions" in `package.json` to ensure the right version of Gift wins when running `yarn install`:

In my `package.json` file I added:

```
{
  ...other package.json stuff...,
  "resolutions": {
    "gift": "^0.10.2"
  }
}
```

This solved the problem for me.